# Any advantage to using "file://" when defining dfs.datanode.data.dir?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Wondering why should one use "file://" when defining the data directory on the datanodes. I know it will work even if I don't use "file://" and simply do something like /mnt/path/ but the official documentation mentions "file:///some/path".

Answer (score 0):

If your question is why it has officially mentioned to use `file://`

- then you know the delimiting character is most commonly the slash `("/")`, the backslash character `("\")`, or colon `(":")`, though some operating systems may use a different delimiter.
- paths are used to represent the directory/file relationships common in modern operating systems, and are essential in the construction of Uniform Resource Locators(URLs).
- resources can be represented by either [absolute or relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths).

Now when you are trying to go to the HDFS directory in Linux based OS then it will hit the target directory or file where the URL starts with `file://`.

- You already know that website URL starts with `http://`, then why you have not wondered in this? I hope you can understand that it depends on the target location, target type and the protocol which have to be transfer or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although, that didn't really answer my question. "file" is used to determine file types, makes sense. However, w.r.t. HDFS datanode directory, why would we care to add the prefix "file://"; to determine file types of stuff stored on the datanodes? Wouldn't that be automatically resolved even if we don't specify the "file://" prefix? My question really is to know if there are any performance advantages to use this prefix against not using it.